# MP3 link Crawler

Tags: mp3, web-crawler

I have been looking into a good way to implement this. I am working on a simple website crawler that will go around a specific set of websites and crawl all the mp3 links into the database.
I don't want to download the files, just crawl the link, index them and be able to search them. So far for some of the sites i have been successful, but for some they use url redirects and stuff which confuses the crawler..

any ideas? how does beemp3.com index all these links?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do an http header request to the links and check their mime type. If it is audio/mpeg chances are you are fetching an mp3 link.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.jimmyr.com/mp3_search.php) something similar to your request (friends at college use it all the time).  Upon entry of **QUERY_TEXT** This search generates a Google query of the following format:

```
QUERY_TEXT intitle:
"index.of" "parent directory" "size" "last modified" "description"
[snd] (mp4|mp3|avi)
-inurl:(jsp|php|html|aspx|htm|cf|shtml|lyrics|mp3s|mp3|index)
-gallery
-intitle:"last modified"
-intitle:(intitle|mp3)
```

Comment: this won't search mp3s, but only pages containing directory listing including mp3 files.

Comment: yeah and that's not really crawling either.. i want to see if a script can go around and index X amount of sites only for mp3 files. Thanks for the answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

What programming languages do you prefer?

**Python:**
There is a very promising crawling framework called [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) (written in python) which is built similar to the [Django Framework](http://www.djangoproject.com/). I haven't used it yet myself but I've been looking at crawlers and Scrapy is the best candidate. It's IIRC not ready out of the box and requires a minimal amount of coding, but it's designed around the DRY principle and is very customizable (somewhat like Django doesn't give you a turn-key website right after installation).

There are many different methods for [URL redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) and your crawler needs to be able to follow these redirects OR in worst case be able to ignore them so it doesn't malfunction.

The site which is redirected *to* must also be in your sites whitelist.

Could you perhaps edit your question and add details on your crawler; Is it written from scratch, is it some turn-key solution, etc?